# Find a convergent power series expansion for the unique solution of $y'(x) = 1 + xy(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

This is a continuation of the last question I asked here: [Show the associated integral operator is a contraction mapping: $x + \int_{0}^{x}ty(t)dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326598/show-the-associated-integral-operator-is-a-contraction-mapping-x-int-0x)

The second part asks "Find a convergent power series expansion for the unique solution". To add to this the DE we are using is $y'(x) = 1 + xy(x)$, $y(0) = 0$ on $[-1,1]$.

To accomplish this task I would have to use Picarditeration to find a pattern to deduce a series. But in order to use Picarditeration with the integral mapping, I have to initially solve my ODE.

For clarity the integral mapping I found was the following: $$TF(x) = \Gamma + \int_{0}^{x}\Phi(t,F(t))dt = 0 + \int_{0}^{x}1 + ty(t) dt = x + \int_{0}^{x}ty(t) dt$$, where $T$ is defined as the integral operator.

To find the series I would perform the following iteration: $$y_{n+1}(x) = Ty_{n}(x)$$

But as I said I have to first solve the ODE. This is where things went astray I think....So the solution I got to the ODE was the following: $$y(x) = \frac{\int_{-1}^{1}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx - 2}{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}$$

Now IF this is the solution to my ODE I would have to plug this into my integral operator and try and obtain a series. As you can see this is a complicated solution to the ODE.  So I'm wondering if I didn't solve this part correctly. I was expecting something simple that I could iteratively find to be some known power series, but this looks like a nightmare if correct.

Feedback on my process? Is the procedure correct  and I just messed up the solution for the ODE?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Why would you have to solve the ODE first in order to compute the iterates $y_{n+1}(x) = Ty_{n}(x)$?

Comment: I'm going based off of what I had seen in my textbook. In the text book when they computed the iterates they had an explicit form for the function $y(t)$. I don't have one unless I solve the ODE. EDIT: They also started with an "assumption" of $y_{0}(t) = 1$. I'm guessing I can't assume such a thing.

Comment: As I understand the task, you are supposed to start with $y_0(0) = 0$, then compute $y_1 = Ty_0$, $y_2 = Ty_1$, ... and try to find a pattern.

Comment: What made you deduce for me to start at $y_{0}(0)  = 0$?.....

Comment: You can start with any function which satisfies the initial value $y(0) = 0$, and a constant function is the most simple choice.

Comment: Have a look at [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem)

Comment: Hmmm......I'm not going to question what you said, but maybe because I haven't been exposed to too many of these questions yet, but it seems as if all of the forms I could see by starting at such an initial value will always end up in an exponential form.....But I'm probably wrong on that part.

Comment: So we never end up actually solving the ODE in these situations? It is always just establishing its existence?

Comment: The Picard–Lindelöf theorem states that (under the stated condition) the iterates $y_n$ converge to a solution $y$. So if you can determine the general $y_n$ and find its limit then you have solved the ODE.

Comment: Ah. So to hopefully avoid having to try and compute nasty integrals we have this process......Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conditions of the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) are satisfied then the function sequence $(y_n)$ defined iteratively by
$$
 y_0(x) = 0 \, , \\
 y_{n+1}(x) = Ty(x) = x + \int_0^x t y_n(t) \, dt
$$
converge to a solution of the initial value problem. This is called Picard-iteration.

The first iterates are
$$
\begin{align}
y_0(x) &= 0 \\
y_1(x) &= x + \int_0^x 0 \, dt = x \, , \\
y_2(x) &= x + \int_0^x t^2 \, dt = x + \frac 13 x^3 \, \\
y_3(x) &= x + \int_0^x \left(t^2 + \frac 13 t^4 \right)\, dt = x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 5} x^5\, .
\end{align}
$$

Your task is to determine the general iterate $y_n$ by detecting a pattern in that sequence.

Then determine $y(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}y_n(x)$ (in the form of a power-series). That is the solution to the initial value problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$$

So

$$y^{'}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}$$

import these power series to main differential equation $y^{'}(x)=1+xy(x)$to receive to

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}=1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}$$

by simplifying this equation:

$$a_{1}=1 , a_{3}=\frac{1}{3}, a_{5}=\frac{1}{15}, \cdot\cdot\cdot,a_{2n-1}=\frac{1}{1*3*5*\cdot\cdot\cdot*(2n-1)}$$
$$a_{2}=\frac{a_{0}}{2} , a_{4}=\frac{a_{0}}{8}, a_{6}=\frac{a_{0}}{48}, \cdot\cdot\cdot,a_{2n}=\frac{a_{0}}{2*4*6*\cdot\cdot\cdot*(2n)}$$

since $y(0)=0$ so $a_{0}=0$ and $a_{2n}=0$

$$y(x)=x+\frac{1}{3}x^{3}+\frac{1}{15}x^{5}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

This series is too similar to $tan(x)$ for $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ that :

$$tan(x)=x+\frac{1}{3}x^{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^{5}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

since for each $x$ in $[-1,1]$ $tan(x)$ converges to a specific value, so $y(x)$ also converges too a specific value. We know that:

$$tan(x)>y(x)$$ for $1>x\ge0$

and $$tan(x)<y(x)$$ for $0\ge x>-1$